# .map In React.js

Tags: javascript

I have this file CarsData.js (content some info)

```
const CarsData = [
  { id: "car_01",  image: imageToyota,     title: "Toyota",      type: "SUV" },
  { id: "car_02",  image: imageAudi,       title: "Audi",        type: "SUV" },
  { id: "car_03",  image: imageNissan,     title: "Nissan",      type: "CAR" },
  { id: "car_04",  image: imageKia,        title: "Kia",         type: "TRUCK" }
]

export default CarsData
```

and I display all the code in this section CardsCars.js

```
const CardsCars = () => {

  const card = CarsData.map(car => {
    return <CardCar image={car.image} title={car.title} type={car.type}/>
  })

  return (
  <>
    <div className='row'>

        {card} //display all the info in CarsData

    </div>
  </>
  )
}

export default CardsCars
```

How can I display only 2 info from CarsData.js (not 4 info)

Comment: Do you wany only the first two or any random two?

Comment: @wonderflame first two and random ?

Comment: @NazarKardan *which two of the four things do you want displayed*? The answer depends. For instance `CarsData.slice(0, n).map(...)` will give you the first `n` elements of the array, but if you don't just want the first two you need something else.

Comment: "@wonderflame first two and random ?" I didn't understand your answer

Comment: @wonderflame I mean how can i display the first and second?
and if i want to display only 2 info random?

Comment: by using [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). This has nothing to do with React so much as with just "how do I use JS arrays" to which the answer is "lots of handy functions built in, give them a read-over".

Comment: You can display first two as @JaredSmith mentioned: `CarsData.slice(0,2).map(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "slice()" method which returns selected elements in an array, as a new array. Then You can run "map()" to show the data.

```
CarsData.slice(0,2).map((car) => (<CardCar image={car.image} title={car.title} type={car.type}/>));
```

In this case, the first 2 info will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you It's work 
can I display 2 info random ?

Comment: @NazarKardan I covered that case in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want `n` random numbers, you may consider the following approach:

```
const randomNElements = (arr = [], n = 2) => {
  const copy = [...arr];
  const result = [];
  const length = Math.min(n, copy.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const [randomElement] = copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length), 1);

    result.push(randomElement);
  }

  return result;
};
```

It doesn't mutate the initial array and doesn't preserve the order of selected elements from initial array