# How can I make different variables both pick a random different element from the same array?

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing JavaScript and wanted to create a simple rock, paper, scissors games. But I can't figure out how to make it choose a random element from an array without duplicating the array and the random function?

Here's what I have:

```
let moves1 = ["rock", "paper", "cissors"];
let moves2 = ["rock", "paper", "cissors"];

// --- Picks a random element from the array ---
let random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * moves1.length);
let random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * moves2.length);

let player1Choice = moves1[random1];
let player2Choice = moves2[random2];
let player1Score = 0;
let player2Score = 0;

console.log('Player 1 chose: ' + player1Choice);
console.log('Player 2 chose: ' + player2Choice);
```

How can I avoid having to duplicate them?

If I don't duplicate the array and create two variables then, both player1Choice & player2Choice always have the same result.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB7a2.png)

Comment: What about using a function?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76204313/21637817) work for you?

Comment: the function from my previous comment can be used as follows: `const [player1Choice, player2Choice] = randomNElements(["rock", "paper", "scissors"], 2)`. Though, with this function, there is no possibility to get the same value for two users

Comment: I mean... the array certainly doesn't need to be duplicated, you can remove one without changing much of anything. everything else... you need two values, so it's not crazy to have a separate place to store each and repeated initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might implement this using objects (for the players) and a couple of supporting functions (including for choosing from the array), with comments explaining what's going on.

To reduce repetition, you could also put the players into an array (like `players = [p1, p2];`), and then loop though the array when you're setting player choices and the like. (I originally included this in the example, along with code to play multiple rounds, but there might already be a lot here for a beginner to digest, so I ended up removing it in the interest of simplicity and brevity.)

```js
// Sets up the shapes array and two player objects,
//   then plays one round
const
  shapes = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"],
  p1 = { name: "River", score: 0, choice: null },
  p2 = { name: "Mal",   score: 0, choice: null };
playRound();


// Assigns random choices and determines round winner
function playRound(){
  
  // Randomly sets the current choice for each player
  p1.choice = randomIndexFrom(shapes);
  p2.choice = randomIndexFrom(shapes);
  console.log(p1.name, "chose", shapes[p1.choice]);
  console.log(p2.name, "chose", shapes[p2.choice]);
  
  // Gets winner and increments score (if any winner)
  const winner = findWinner();
  if(winner){
    winner.score++;
    console.log(winner.name + " wins \n");
  }
  else{ console.log("Tie"); }
}


// Returns the winning player object if any, or null on ties
function findWinner(){
  // eg:
  //   River: paper (index 1), Mal: rock (index 0)
  //   0 - 1 = -1; `case:-1` says River wins
  switch(p2.choice - p1.choice){
    case -1: case  2: return p1;
    case  1: case -2: return p2;
    case  0: return null;
    default: throw("This comparison is bollocks");
  }
}

function randomIndexFrom(array){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}
```